Can we refer to "infinity" as a property of a set in ZFC/FOL?
I understand we have the Axiom of Infinity and have "access" to an infinite set, but is there a way to say in first-order logic "set A is infinite" or refer to its cardinality?
The first thing that would come to mind is establishing the existence of a bijection and so forth but that sounds to me like second-order logic (I'm a newbie and can be way off).
Also I get that there is no concept of "element inside a set" in ZFC but rather everything is a set, so I'm not sure If I can say something like "all the elements inside set A considered together are infinitely many".
This is just a theoretical question with no specific application in mind; I don't have any theorem I want to prove with this. I just want to better understand the concept of "infinity" (if that even exists) within ZFC/FOL framework.
Other questions maybe related to this:

Here they define the set of infinite subsets of the naturals directly referencing the cardinality, $A=\{S\subseteq\mathbb{N}\mid |S|=\infty\}$, but I'm not sure if the context is ZFC/FOL.
Here instead they mention


For first-order logic, the answer is that cardinality is largely undetectable


but I'm also not sure if this applies to ZFC as well (I imagine it might and also wonder then if the more vague "infinite" property is also out of scope).


Not very clear, but yes Cardinality is the way to count the elements of sets. For finite sets, the result is the same of the usual "counting" process, but it applies also to infinite sets.

Hi Lucas, welcome to MSE. I think neither of your links really addresses your question. I think you have a common misconception about first-order set theory. The fun of ZFC is that the domain of discourse is the universe of sets. Because "a function from $\Bbb N$ to $X$" is itself a set, this means that "there exists an injective function from $\Bbb N$ to $X$" is a first-order statement of ZFC, as the quantifier is over sets. (There are also other ways to define "infinite" - eg "there is an injective non-surjective function $X \to X$")

Thanks, I didn't know the functions counted also as sets. In a way the "everything is a set" seems to bypass the limits of first-order logic (rough and probably wrong interpretation; I mean that FOL when viewed alone seems much more restricted than when applied to ZFC).

This "bypassing" is a complicated and sometimes paradoxical property indeed! It took me a long time to really get to grips with the behaviour of models of ZFC. In some sense they do bypass constraints, but in some other sense they really don't. If you know the compactness theorem, then you should be able to follow the proof that if there's a model of ZFC, then there's a model $M$ of ZFC with a set $X \in M$ such that $M \models |X| \ge 1$ and $M \models |X| \ge 2$ and so on for each natural number, but also such that $M \models \text{"$X$ is finite"}$. This is in important example!

I can understand your confusion. Your second quote is an informal description of an aspect of first-order logic. Likewise, your question "Is there a way to say in first-order logic 'set A is infinite' or refer to its cardinality?" isn't quite precise enough for a one-sentence answer.
I think it will help for spell out some details. We begin with the notion of a model of a theory (an FOL theory, though the concept applies more generally). I'll assume you know that. Now we ask, is there a way to express in FOL that a model is infinite? Countable? Or that some aspect of a model is infinite/countable? The answer is, "sometimes, with some caveats". Looking at some examples will clarify matters. (There are some technical points that I will ignore until the end. This remark is mostly for the cognoscenti who might say things like, "What about SM?")
First an example where (a form of) "finite" cannot be expressed. Let's take the theory of a graph. In one formulation, we have a single binary relation symbol, say $E$; the variables range over the vertices of the graph and $E(a,b)$ means that there is an edge connecting $a$ to $b$. We can easily say that $a$ is connected to $b$ in one step:
$$\exists x(E(a,x)\wedge E(x,b))$$
Likewise, with longer and longer formulas, we can say that there is a path from $a$ to $b$ with 2, 3, 4, etc. steps. But it turns out that there is no formula of FOL that says that there is path from $a$ to $b$ of some finite length. This is a consequence of the Compactenss Theorem of FOL. In this sense, "finite" cannot be expressed in this case.
Even simpler: the formula $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$ asserts that the model has one element. A slightly more complicated formula asserts that it has at most two elements: $\exists x\exists y\forall z(z=x\vee z=y)$. Likewise, you can write formulas for "at most 3", "at most 4", etc. But there is no single formula of this type that says that "there are only finitely many elements in the model".
On the other hand, there are many theories with no finite models. Easy example: a linear ordering with no maximal element. One relation symbol, $<$, and these axioms will do the trick:
$$\begin{align*}&x<y\to x\neq y\\&x<y\wedge y<z\to x<z\\&\forall x\forall y(x<y\vee x=y\vee y<x)\\&\forall x\exists y(x<y)\end{align*}$$
So in this sense, FOL can say something is infinite.
Now let's turn to ZF. This is a FO theory with one relation symbol, $\in$. The details are more complicated, but in ZF you can write a formula specifying $\omega$, (the set of natural numbers $\{0,1,\ldots\}$). Just like the linear ordering example, there is no model of ZF in which $\omega$ is finite. We can also specify the usual linear ordering on $\omega$, and we can write a formula ${\rm finite}(s)$ that says that there is a 1-1 bijection between $s$ and the set of all natural numbers less than some natural number. It looks something like this:
$$\exists f\exists n(n\in\omega\wedge f\text{ is a bijection between }s\text{ and }\{i:i<n\})$$
Fully expanded into the language of ZF, which contains only the one relation symbol $\in$, this would be a pretty long formula, but it can be done.
Often, when we think of models of ZF, we have in mind the so-called "standard" model. In this model, ${\rm finite}(s)$ is true for all finite sets $s$ and false for all infinite sets $s$. In this sense, we can express "finite" in the FO theory ZF.
But there are also other models of ZF, and in particular ones in which $\omega$ contains elements that you might regard as "infinite natural numbers". There is no way in FOL to exclude such models; this is, again, a consequence of the Compactness Theorem. In such a model, $\rm{finite}(s)$ doesn't really capture the notion of finiteness. We say that "a set can be finite when viewed from inside the model, but infinite when viewed from outside". This is an informal description of what's going on.
It's a similar story with countability. There's a formula ${\rm uncountable}(s)$ in ZF that says "$s$ is infinite, but there is no bijection between $s$ and $\omega$". In the so-called standard model of ZF, this is satisfied by exactly the uncountable sets. But there are models of ZF in which there are sets which are "uncountable inside, countable outside". And the reverse: there are models of ZF with "countable inside, uncountable outside" sets--in fact, in which the $\omega$ of the model is uncountable. (Remember that $\omega$ is picked out by a particular formula of ZF.)
All this is a consequence of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.
Now the caveats. First, philosophical issues: there are mathematicians who don't think the phrase "standard model of ZF" has a clear meaning. I've taken a so-called Platonist viewpoint above, as it's harder to describe the situation from other philosophical perspectives.
Also, when I said "there are models of ZF in which...", I'm implicitly appealing to an axiom known as SM. SM is not one of the axioms of ZF. But it's very common in discussions of set theory to add it. If we want to stay strictly inside of ZF, we can cook up similar illustrations of the countability issues, but the description will be more involved. (Basically, we don't go for a model of ZF; just enough of it so we can say "there are uncountably many subsets of the $\omega$". And by "just enough", I don't mean "just some of the axioms", but something more complicated.)

Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm accepting it because for the vagueness of my question this is as good an answer as I can expect. I think the core of my confusion is what you mention in (and it scares me that it's in quotes because that implies I won't find an easier in-depth explanation for it): "a set can be finite when viewed from inside the model, but infinite when viewed from outside". I suspect I might be confusing what I intuitively expect to be called "infinite" and what the model understands for it.

Yes, this "inside vs. outside" shows up all the time in books on logic, model theory, and axiomatic set theory. Typically it's not explained in any depth. Basically, there are two levels, the outer level and the inner level. The outer is usually informal---the sort of mathematical reasoning one learns before one encounter formal logic. This is used to discuss the inner level. The outer level is also known as the meta-level.
